Will there be any frictional force from surface when an external force acts upon a body which is in contact with wall?

When an external force is acting on the given body, will there be opposing friction force or normal force from wall? Or will both come into existence in some specific ratio? Or will normal force exist after exceeding the limiting friction? Also, what would be the equation(s) governing these forces?

According to the third Newton law, there will be $-F_{ext}$ normal force from the wall back on the block.  To verify this, just push down some object which rests on the weighing scales and see how it's "weight" increases, indicating that an object is now affected by total normal force $\vec N=-(\vec W+\vec F_{ext})$.

All of those scenarios are possible. The system is statically indeterminate.
To determine which of these cases is correct requires additional information. Specifically, we need to know the stress in the material. Usually this is determined by measuring the strain and the material’s modulus of elasticity.

I got the point, but let's take in some hypothetical case where the object is completely rigid (strain approx. 0), have equal cross-section area from wall and the surface, corners are perpendicular, will friction and normal increase in some sort of specific ratio or friction will increase like that of decreasing exponential graph till it's limiting value together with normal or something else!Thanks.

It is not possible then. A rigid object makes the system of equations have an infinite number of solutions. That is precisely the problem you have identified in your question and material stress and strain is precisely the solution to the problem.

Let's assign a value of $0.5$ for the coefficient of static friction and $0.2$ for the coefficient of dynamic friction. This means the limiting static friction would be $2.5$ Newtons and the dynamic friction would be $1$ Newton. Now, let's suppose we place a set of bathroom scales between the block and the wall. The question becomes: what will the scales read when a given force is applied to the right on the block?  The reading on the scales is equivalent to normal reaction force of the wall. There is no friction force on the wall because there is no vertical motion of the block parallel to the wall.
Let's say we initially apply a force of $2 \, \mathrm{N}$ to the right. Since this is less than the limiting static friction, the block does not slide horizontally. However the scales do not read zero, because the block is not infinitely rigid and will bend slightly exerting a force on the scales, even when the base of the block remains stationary. When the system is in equilibrium, we might have the wall exerting a force of $0.5 \, \mathrm{N}$ to the left and the static friction exerting a force of $1.5 \, \mathrm{N}$ also to the left. We could equally have the wall exerting a normal reaction force of $1 \, \mathrm{N}$ and the static friction providing the remain $1 \, \mathrm{N}$ to the left. As Dale correctly points out there are an infinite number of possible solutions and we cannot provide a definitive solution without knowing all the details of the elasticity of the block and how much it deforms or bends.
Now let's increase the force to the right until it exceeds the limiting static friction and current normal force of the wall. The block will start sliding to the right and the friction force is now the dynamic sliding force of $1 \, \mathrm{N}$. If the applied force is $7 \, \mathrm{N}$, the block will come to a stop when the normal reaction force of the wall builds up to $6 \, \mathrm{N}$. Once it stops the scales would read $6 \, \mathrm{N}$ and the static friction provides the remaining $1 \, \mathrm{N}$ to the left.
Now what happens when we remove the force applied to the right? Initially there is a normal force of $6 \, \mathrm{N}$ from the wall, but the block cannot remain static because the maximum static friction is limited to $2.5 \, \mathrm{N}$. The block slides to the left with a dynamic friction of $1 \, \mathrm{N}$ and comes to rest when the normal force of the wall drops to $1 \, \mathrm{N}$. This means we end up with $1 \, \mathrm{N}$ reading on the scales and an opposing $1 \, \mathrm{N}$ due to the static friction providing the required force to keep the system in equilibrium.
All the above ignores the effects of momentum. For example in the last case if the block has sufficient momentum due to being accelerated by the reaction force of the wall, the block could continue sliding until there is no force reading on the scales. The above conclusions are reasonably valid if the forces and distances are small and the friction is reasonably high, such that momentum effects are negligible. However it is fair to say this is a very difficult system to model exactly without having a lot more information.

Dynamic sliding friction do not necessarily need relative motion
between surface, it can also occur when static friction value is
exceeded just like in this case, when something like wall stops the
object from moving. Aarunya Kumar

I do not believe this is correct. Dynamic sliding friction only occurs when there is relative motion between the surfaces, hence the name. In an exaggerated model of friction, imagine the surfaces have saw tooth ridges on them. When stationary the teeth interlock. In order to move the block, the block has to rise up by the height of the triangular teeth, which requires a certain amount of energy. Once the block starts moving the teeth bounce off each other and part of the time the two blocks are not even in direct contact with each other. This reduces the average amount of force to move the blocks and this is one reason dynamic friction is less than the static friction. There are other forces present such as Van der Waals and electrostatic forces that are most active when the objects are in intimate static contact.
if the applied force exceeds the the static force, the wall has to produce a reaction force to the block in order to stop the block moving. In order for the wall to produce a reaction force, it has to be deformed or compress and this means the block has to actually move or bend, (either way the centre of mass of the block has moved slightly) in order for the wall to react. The intuition is difficult because we tend to think of walls as rigid objects. For better intuition, think of the wall as a bow string under tension or simply as a spring. In order for the string to produce an opposing force, it has to be stretched (or the spring has to be compressed) and this means the block must move.

When constant external force is removed, normal will not automatically
set to 0 rather it will decrease to 0 in a very small time period.

In the example I gave, when the external force was removed, there was a $1N$ reaction normal force opposing a $1N$ static friction force. In order for the reaction force to fall to zero, the wall will have to decompress or the bow string will have straighten out or spring will have to extend fully back to its relaxed state. In order to do this, the block will have to be moved to the left, but this is impossible, because the static friction always exactly matches the wall normal force and there is no net force to move the block. Therefore the normal force will not drop to zero.

So does that mean that if we neglect momentum effects, once we stop applying force to the right of the block, there will still be a normal force of $1N$ and it won’t decrease? Sounds counterintuitive…

Dale had satisfies me with his answer, but yours has boosted my thinking, here are few points I learned from this, please correct me if I am wrong. 1) Relation between normal and friction is "Normal=m*friction^n" where m and n depends on the true strain of block. 2) Dynamic sliding friction do not necessarily need relative motion between surface, it can also occur when static friction value is exceeded just like in this case, when something like wall stops the object from moving. Point 3,4,5 are in next comment.


When constant external force is removed, normal will not automatically set to 0 rather it will decrease to 0 in a very small time period. 4) Paragraph 4 somehow tells about collision also, if the decreasing normal force exceeds the friction force, block will move in opposite direction (new way to think collision). Also, from here we can know impulse by the graph of this normal force and time, then we can calculate velocity. 5) Dynamic friction decreases from +ve 1N to -ve 1N without having static friction when dynamic friction reaches 0N. (Rest in next comment)


But I think that should not be true, static friction would have occured but as the normal force decreases from 6N, it would have exceeded the static friction with no any time and suddenly dynamic friction would have come into existence. Also, block would have move a little away from the wall.

@Rϵlaτινιτy and Aarunya Kumar. I have extended my answer to address some of your comments.

Now, I get it! This is one of the most insightful and thought-provoking answers I’ve encountered so far on PSE, $+1$!
